# A Question about Expected Value: There are 5 balls in an opaque box, whose colors are white, red, blue, green and yellow, respectively.

Tags: probability, expected-value

There are 5 balls in an opaque box, whose colors are white, red, blue, green and yellow, respectively. They are not distinguishable unless being taken out. Each time Amy uniformly at random takes a ball out from the box (with replacement).

(a) What is the expected number of times of taking to get the first two consecutive white balls?

(b) What is the expected number of times of taking to get the first consecutive white and red balls? (a white ball immediately followed by a red ball)

I have no idea how to start with this question. Aren't the probability of (a) and (b) the same? And why doesn't the question specify the number of times to take a ball?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question by means of an edit (not a comment), and tell us where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

> I have no idea how to start with this question.

Once Amy obtains the first white ball, she either end the game on the next draw (having drawn another white ball), or returns to looking for the next white ball.

Partitioning on the roll after the first white ball gives rise to a recursion.

So let $B$ be the count of draws until the first (next) white ball, and $C$ the count of balls until the first two consecutive white balls.  Let $W$ be the event that a particular draw is a white ball.  Find $\mathsf E(C)$ as a *recursive expression* of $\mathsf E(B), \mathsf P(W),$ and $\mathsf E(C)$.

---

So, the expected time until consecutive white balls to take at least one more draw than the time to find the first white ball, plus, the probability for that subsequent draw not being a white ball times the expected time until consecutive white balls from that point.

$\qquad\mathsf E(C) = \mathsf E(B+1) +\mathsf P(W^\complement)\,\mathsf E(C)\\\therefore\quad \mathsf E(C)=\dfrac{1+\mathsf E(B)}{\mathsf P(W)}$

---

> Aren't the probability of (a) and (b) the same?

No.

The second part is much like the first, with a little wrinkle.  Once Amy finds a white ball, the next draw will be red, white, or another colour.

---

> And why doesn't the question specify the number of times to take a ball?

It does.  Amy returns balls after each draw, and so may draw each one many times over.

> > Each time Amy uniformly at random takes a ball out from the box (with replacement).

Comment: Sorry, I still don't quite catch what you are saying. Could you please explain more detailedly? Thanks!